# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my android, and then created new project.

But, when I tried to run this application, it's just a default application - no packages imported or changes made, it throws an error:

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':wakelock' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
```

I'm not sure what the problem is: Could it be that i didn't install my environments and stuff properly or something.

Please help for i have made my application, but before launching am facing this error...So devastating, already tried for 3 days!

Comment: I need help with it too…very urgent bro!

Comment: change `kotlin` version inside  `wakelock`  to the  version in your project `android gradle file`

Answer (score 0):

What version of the AGP are you using?

Seems like you need to update your AGP to a newer version that actually supports Kotlin version 1.5.20.

Try running the AGP Upgrade Assistant at the very bottom of the Tools menu.

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration, but I don't know how, but I have solve the issues! Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by changing the following in wakelock build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    .....
}
```

[image]